# [discord.py]Удаление сообщение после выполнениыя команды

Tags: discord, discord.py

Поменялась версия и теперь не понимаю как удалить сообщение после выполнения команды

```
client.delete_message()
```

Раньше было так, но теперь поменялась команда.
 `await ctx.message.delete(ctx)` Вроде так, но оно не сработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно написать надо так:

```
async def команда(ctx, amount = сумма):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделано верно,но только надо без ctx,он и так понимает,какое сообщение удалять

```py
await ctx.message.delete()
```